# Google iPhone app status bar animation how did they do it?

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, statusbar

I was playing with the Google App for iPhone and when i viewed a website the title of the page appeared over the classic status bar with a nice fade-in animation, after 4-5 seconds the title view disappeared with a nice fade-out animation.

How did they do that? did they hide the status bar with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES] and then added somehow the animation in the empty space? from my experience you can't fill that space without telling a viewController to "want fullscreen layout".

Another idea using "wants fullscreen layout" is to hide the status bar with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO] and add an UIView as a subview to the controller's view and animate that(fade-in/fade-out at regular intervals).

Any pointers on how can i achieve this?

[alt text http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/2158/screenshot2010031110355.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/2158/screenshot2010031110355.png)
[alt text http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/8892/screenshot2010031110360.png](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/8892/screenshot2010031110360.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to hide the iPhone's status bar by calling

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden = YES;
```

and add your view there!